# Set element attribute value in XML with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML:

```
<appsettings>

    <add key="MDXQueryDirectory" value="" />

    <add key="URLPrefix" value="/Manager" />

</appsettings>
```

and code:

```
 XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"config_path");


 var element = doc.Elements("add")
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("key").Value == "MDXQueryDirectory");


 element.SetAttributeValue("value", txtMDXQueryDirectory.Text);
```

I want to assign the txtMDXQueryDirectory textbox data to the MDXQueryDirectory appSsetting. First I use `Single` method but it doesn't work and I researched on google I found this [page](http://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2009/12/17/fixing-linq-error-sequence-contains-no-elements.aspx) so bugs solve related that article. But know `SingleOrDefault` method doesn't work. It throws `NullPointerException (Object reference not set to an instance an object)`

How can I solve problem or maybe you suggest different idiom to set value data in xml?

Comment: Are the "doc" or "doc.Elements("add")" or "x.Attribute("key")" objects not null? Have you checked?

Comment: Big possibility Lİnq query didn't find correct xml node. The following code example provide your question answer.But code still not working.

Comment: Please check all 3 things I mentioned to see what exactly causes that exception. You don't have any safety checks so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string config_file = @"config_file_path";

 var element = doc.Element("appSettings").Elements("add")
                           .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("key").Value.ToString() == "MDXQueryDirectory");

 element.SetAttributeValue("value", txtMDXQueryDirectory.Text);
 doc.Save(@"config_file_path");
```

This code block work fine. I think the problem was related xml nodes in my side. Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the query where you're selecting the element to update, it should be:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"config_path");

 var element = doc.Descendants().Elements("add")
               .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("key").Value == "MDXQueryDirectory");

 element.SetAttributeValue("value", txtMDXQueryDirectory.Text);

 doc.Save(@"config_path");
```

You should also be using `XDocument` rather than `XElement` when getting the file.

**Note:** `XDocument.Load(@"config_path")` - should point to the location of your XML file. Currently it does not.

Comment: it doesn't work in my side still I get "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: What line does this fall on? If your XML is identical to that posted in your OP then the error is somewhere else in your code because I have tested this locally and it is fine.

Comment: There is no need for XDocument here. There rarely is.

Comment: @TayfurYılmaz - the key solution here is `Descendants`, that ought to work.

Comment: x.Attribute("key").Value == "MDXQueryDirectory"); this line throw a exception @DGibbs

Comment: Please post the *exact* XML you're running this code against. Do you have an element in the file with the key `MDXQueryDirectory`?

Comment: @HenkHolterman What does it mean? Your suggestion "I should remove this method?"

Comment: I mean that `XElement doc` is fine.

Comment: @TayfurYılmaz Can you confirm that `"config_path"` is just placeholder and that this isn't the actual path you're using in your code? Because I can see some issues if it is... - regarding Henks comments, `XElement` is fine to use but I felt that `XDocument` makes more sense given the context

Comment: config_path path notifications correct but  When I want to get 'MDXQueryDirectory' (key Data) somethings goes wrong

Comment: string config_file = @"config_file_path";
 
     var element = doc.Element("appSettings").Elements("add")
                               .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("key").Value.ToString() == "MDXQueryDirectory");

     element.SetAttributeValue("value", txtMDXQueryDirectory.Text);
     doc.Save(@"config_file_path";

This code block work fine. I think the problem was related xml nodes in my side. Thansk for all replies.